# Unity window placement

Tags: unity, unity-dash, window

When I launch an application (by typing its name into the Dash and hitting enter, clicking on its icon in the panel, or using a shortcut - it doesn't matter) the application window appears in the topmost left corner, next to the Dash.

**Is there a way to have a better window placement by default?** And by 'better', I mean mostly where I expect the window to be - usually in the center, but also considering other windows.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Here you'll find [Place Windows](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place) plugin. AFAIK, this is the only way to customize window placement in Compiz.